# phpmyadmin - localhost.sql import - #1046 - No database selected

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have an old backup of some localhost databases (localhost.sql), which needs to be imported into PhPMyAdmin on a Windows 7 machine with XAMPP installed.

When I try to import localhost.sql (containing multiple databases) in PhPMyAdmin, I get the following error:

**#1046 - No database selected**

With a single database, you would simply create a new database with the same name and import to that. As this is an old backup, I am not able to recreate the export and I also don´t know the database names that are inside localhost.sql.

Is there a way to recover this?

Comment: Open your *localhost.sql* file with a text editor and search for a command like this : `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db-name`. If it doesn't exist, it means you have to create a database by hand and then do the import.

Comment: @acknowledge "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" does not exist in the db. So I will have to create a database called "localhost.sql" and then import into that?

Comment: Ok, so it probably means that it was an export of only one database. So first create a database (the name is not important). Then go into the database by clicking on it in the left pane. Then click on *import* and import your file from here.

Comment: @acknowledge No, localhost.sql contains multiple databases of which I don´t know the individual names.

Comment: Weird. So you have to analyze the content of you file to understand it. If you want help, copy the first 30 lines of the file here and I'll help you.

Comment: @acknowledge Having a look at the sql-code shows that localhost.sql contains 11 individual databases, which I can now identify by name. The question is how to reestablish those in PhPMyAdmin now?

Comment: Ok. That's a good point. So your file contains creation of the tables (CREATE TABLE ...) + insertion of the data (INSERT INTO ...), is it right ?

You can achieve what you want by adding the creation of the databases in your file (something like "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS yourdbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;") and then say that the next commands concern this db (write "USE yourdbname;"). You do this for each of your 11 databases.

Comment: @acknowledge Ok, great. Where exactly would I have to place this?

Comment: Just before the commands that create the tables and fill the data. Here's the sequence : Create database, use, create table, insert, create table, insert, ..., create database, use, create table, insert, create table, insert, create table, insert and so on. Eleven times.

Comment: Or you can create the databases by hand, then split your files in multiple files, one for each database. And then you import file by file in the related database.

Comment: @acknowledge Ok thanks. I finally got it working and was able to recover all databases. If you want to add this as an official answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I wrote the answer. I'm glad I could help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities to do this :

- Create all the databases by hand in phpMyAdmin. Split your .sql file so that each file corresponds to a database. And finally you import each file in the correct database.
- Edit your *localhost.sql* file and add the commands to create the databases ("CREATE DATABASE ...") in the right place. Then you import all at once.